# Is there an offlineOpenCL compiler (for NVIDIA graphics cards)?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, nvidia

The normal way to run an OpenCL program is to include the openCL kernel that is compiled at runtime (*online compilation*).

But I've seen examples of compiling OpenCL to binary before, called *offline compilation*. I'm aware of the disadvantages (reducing compatibility across hardware).

There used to be an offline compiler at http://www.fixstars.com/en/ but it does not seems to be available anymore.

So is there an offline compiler for OpenCL available, in particular for NVIDIA-based cards?

Comment: clGetProgramInfo and  CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES and cards?

Comment: So, you mean that you can use a standard OpenCl function to compile to binary and later use this binary to run your compiled OpenCL program?

Comment: Maybe only similar platforms.

Comment: I agree with huseyin tugrul buyukisik, you can do that though OpenCL API at run time. For example, the 1st time your application runs, you compile the kernel and generate a binary, saving it somewhere in the storage. Next time when you run the same application, the pre-compiled kernel binary can be directly used.

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested that nvcc.exe in NVidia's CUDA SDK could compile .cl files with

```
nvcc -x cu file.cl -o file.out -lOpenCL
```

...but it says missing cl.exe at least on Windows. This might be worth checking out, however: http://clcc.sourceforge.net/

As well as:

- https://github.com/HSAFoundation/CLOC (AMD-maintained offline compiler)
- https://github.com/Maratyszcza/clcc (includes also links to above ones and more)

Comment: Missing cl.exe would imply that it depends on Microsoft's C/C++ compiler, which is bundled with Visual Studio. Is that listed as a prerequisite for NVIDIA's CUDA SDK?

Comment: @CodyGray The nvcc usually requires a C-Compiler in the background (i.e. it's using the C-compiler for the C-part, and doing its own magic for the CUDA- or OpenCL part). In general, @Roalt: One workaround could be to write a small, standalone application that basically is a wrapper around the respective `clCompileProgram`-(etc) calls, so that you obtain a small, command-line compiler that receives a bunch of CL-input files, compiles them, and writes the result (that is then obtained with `CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES`) into output files. I'm surprised if there really is no such thing yet...